# How can a for of loop be made to iterate down instead of up thru the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can a `for of` loop in es6 be made to start on the last item in the array and go down to the first instead of how it normally uses the `variable++` behavior to iterate from first to last in the array's index.

Comment: `Array.reverse` - not ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for..of` loop is one-directional, proceeding through the iterator's natural order. You can't change the direction of the iterator.

You could, of course, use a simple `for` loop instead:

```
for (let i = theArray.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    let entry = theArray[i];
    // ...
}
```

...but to use an interator for this (e.g., with `for..of`), you have to change what it's iterating over, or the iterator it's using.

One way to do that is to reverse the order of the array first. Unfortunately, `Array#reverse` modifies the array *in place*, and so if you want to keep the array in its original order, you have to clone it first ([live example on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20theArray%20%3D%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22Reversed%3A%22)%3B%0Afor%20(let%20entry%20of%20theArray.slice().reverse())%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(entry)%3B%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(%22But%20original%20order%20unchanged%3A%22)%3B%0Afor%20(let%20entry%20of%20theArray)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(entry)%3B%0A%7D)):

```
for (let entry of theArray.slice().reverse()) {
    // ...
}
```

Another way is to write a reusable generator function that loops backward through an array:

```
function *backward(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    yield a[i];
  }
}
```

then:

```
let theArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
for (let entry of backward(theArray)) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

[Live example on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20*backward(a)%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%20a.length%20-%201%3B%20i%20%3E%3D%200%3B%20--i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20a%5Bi%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20theArray%20%3D%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D%3B%0Afor%20(let%20entry%20of%20backward(theArray))%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(entry)%3B%0A%7D)

As [RGraham points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539288/how-can-a-for-of-loop-be-made-to-iterate-down-instead-of-up-thru-the-array#comment54859763_33539344), now that we can subclass arrays, you could even create an array subclass that provides `backward` as its default iterator.

Gosh, so many options. :-)

Comment: simple `for` loop is the best way, this code is clear and easy to read

Comment: @AndrewEvt: Iterators are a powerful abstraction, that's why we have them. :-) But for just looping backward, yeah, hard to beat a simple `for` now we have block scoping.

Comment: Could also subclass Array and use your `backward` function as the default iterator. Not now, but in the future :)

Comment: @RGraham: Oooooooh. 'tis true.

Answer (score -2):

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = array.length; i--;) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}

//5
//4
//3
//2
//1
```

[Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20array%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%3B%0Afor%20(let%20i%20%3D%20array.length%3B%20i--%3B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(array%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A%7D)